# 1 application many PayPal accounts

Tags: paypal, multiple-accounts

I am writing an web application where historically they have used their own PayPal account to take payments for classes run by external self-employed staff. However the tax system has changed and the charity would like thier clients to book through their website (just as before) but pay the freelance instructor directly via PayPal.

The question is; will PayPal allow from one website payment requests for multiple individuals. I am imagining that self-emplyed staff log on to the site enter payment details and the site does the rest.

A simple, 'yes it is possible will do' as I can see myself farming out this part of the application due to time

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not new for the PayPal api, as you might know, shopping cart software needs to do that in case of a marketplace.

You have to ask the "self-employed" for permission. This will give you a token.

This explains the permissions service.

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/permissions-service/integration-guide/PermissionsAbout/

This gives you the technical know how.

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/permissions-service/ht_permissions-invoice/

Then you need to send these 2 extra parameters in your requests, the token and the account.
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/invoicing/ht_invoicing-3p/

In the end it will be your app calling PayPal on behalf of xxx account.